# One-line configuration for both www and non-www VirtualHost

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost, apache2.4

I have many `VirtualHost` and it seems that we need to do these two lines each time:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
```

Is there a one-line solution that allows to do this?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName *.example.com   # works for both http://example.com and http://www.example.com
```

i.e. without having to duplicate `example.com`?

Comment: No.  And why woud you want to?  You pay by the character? :-)

Comment: @Nic3500 I do all my server config backups on a [5 1/4"](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ordinateurs/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/01180936/Floppy-Disk.jpg).

Comment: Then consider using gzip/bzip2/xz/etc... ;-)

Comment: I am not sure I have fully grasped your question but according to https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html `ServerAlias example.com *.example.com`
then requests for all hosts in the example.com domain will be served by the www.example.com virtual host. The wildcard characters * and ? can be used to match names. Of course, you can't just make up names and place them in ServerName or ServerAlias. You must first have your DNS server properly configured to map those names to an IP address associated with your server.

Comment: see also: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html Using `_default_` vhosts

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible.

`ServerName` is used to uniquely identify protocol, name and port of a host. It accepts only one parameter and no wildcard.

You can use wildcards in `ServerAlias`, and also specify multiple names on it:

```
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

or

```
ServerAlias www1.example.com www2.example.com www3 foo
```

Source: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias

Comment: So could I use *only* `ServerAlias *.example.com` and no `ServerName`?

Comment: Unfortunately not, IIRC each vhost must have a `ServerName`.

Answer (score 0):

A trick I like to do is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Include                 /.../example.com.conf.include
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Include                 /.../example.com.conf.include
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    Include                 /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf #optional, maybe you should not do that
</VirtualHost>
```

and the xxx.conf.include file like:

```
ServerAdmin someone@somewhere.tld
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias example.com *.example.com andmore.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
ErrorLog /.../example.com_error.log
CustomLog /.../example.com_custom.log combined

<Directory /var/www/html/example.com>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

This way, you can have HTTP and HTTPS virtual hosts in exactly the same configuration file.

Specifically to your question,

```
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

should do the trick

Comment: *Specifically to your question `ServerAlias *.example.com` should do the trick*: we still need to add another `ServerName`, right?

Comment: Oh ahh... sorry... yes, you still do need the `ServerName`. I wanted to suggest you check if there are any ways of including variables into the config, but as I dont know much about that, I didnt suggest. My above solution just saves a lot more writing and double editing, so I thought maybe you prefer that, instead of saving one line.